# Why there is no filter function of Stream in idris?

Tags: functional-programming, idris, codata

There is `filter : (a -> Bool) -> List a -> List a` for List, but there is no `filter : (a -> Bool) -> Stream a -> Stream a` for Stream, why?

Is there some alternatives to do the similar jobs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Functions in Idris are total by default, and the totality checker will rightly refuse to accept filter on streams, which is a somewhat canonical example of a non-productive definition on a coinductive type: what would `filter isEven` *return* when applied to the stream of odd nats?

Check [Productive Coprogramming with Guarded Recursion](http://bentnib.org/productive.pdf), where you will find this very same example and a nice intro to totality in the context of coinductive types.

Comment: And cf. [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11417170_9) by Bertot for a productive definition of a filter-like function on streams.